# Corner button to appear and disappear while scrolling the page

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var $window = $(window),
  $document = $(document),
  button = $('.button-ctus');

button.css({
  opacity: 1,
});

$window.on('scroll', function() {
  if (($window.scrollTop() + $window.height()) == $document.height()) {
    button.stop(true).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 250);
  } else {
    button.stop(true).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 250);
  }
});
```

In this code the right corner button disappears when you scroll down to the bottom of the page.

However I would like to have this button hiding in the middle of the page where there is a part related to this button.

In other words, to have this button disappear when the related part of the page is visible in the screen and appear when the related part is not visible on the page.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to add css lines to the part below, but it didn't work                                                                 button.css({
  opacity: 1,
});

Comment: That wont do it indeed. Could you create a jsfiddle with what you have so far. ill take a look into it. Also try to get into the basics of javascript!

Comment: well, I am new in JavaScript. I am afraid I will not be able to create what you suggested.

Comment: Well then its almost impossible to solve. Why cant you reproduce in a jsfiddle?